# Chef and git checkout

Tags: git, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm currently using chef to deploy a server on opsworks and then using a 'deploy' recipe, deploy an app from a private repo.

Everything works as expected, in that my repo is cloned correctly. Although it clones my directory I end up with a number of subdirectories e.g

- current
- release

What I'd like to do is just get the master branch not in a subfolder, so I am in essence getting the root of my web app from git.

my current chef code looks like

```
deploy '/var/www/html' do
  repo 'myrepo.git'
  git_ssh_wrapper "/git-ssh-wrapper" # For private Git repos 
  deploy_to '/var/www/html'
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink.clear
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
  action :deploy
end
```

I'm not sure if either the 'action' is incorrect above, or should I be using 'deploy_revision' instead of deploy here?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Was it a sparse checkout and a shallow clone that you needed? Looks like the git resource of chef doesn't give everything we need to solve that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `git` resource instead of a `deploy` resource.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting this. I'm not overly familiar with chef so had to familiarise myself with the options on the git resource. Perhaps you could expand your answer a bit more for others who view this (e.g git_ssh_wrapper should just be ssh_wrapper and 'action :deploy' doesn't exist etc. as I only discovered a few of these through trial and error (clearly didn't look at the docs thoroughly enough!)

Comment: You can find it all in the Chef documentation (https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html), including an example at the top.

Comment: As I say I found the docs,but just thought it might be good to expand on your answer with more than just a link for potential future viewers as obviously urls aren't always permanent and then everything would be in one place, but no matter.

Comment: Copy-pasting the Chef docs seems like a poor use of everyone's time. It is more likely my answer here will be outdated than the Chef docs will cease to exist.